Dockerfile For C# Azure Function App With PlayWright
New and learning Dockerfile; need help to edit the following Dockerfile to containerize a C# Azure Function App with Playwright.
Here's part of the function code:

    using System.Net;
    using Func_MyFunction.Interfaces;
    using Func_MyFunction.Models;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Microsoft.Playwright;


        [Function("HttpExample")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }


The other endpoints that will checks the UI of an URL and sends an email if it's not visible.
This is the Dockerfile (with line numbers)
 1. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0 AS base
 2. WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
 3. EXPOSE 80
 4. 
 5. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
 6. ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
 7. WORKDIR /src
 8. COPY . .
 9. RUN ls -la
10. RUN dotnet restore "./Func_MyFunction.csproj"
11. RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Playwright
12. RUN dotnet build "./Func_MyFunction.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
13. RUN playwright install
14. 
15. FROM build AS publish
16. ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
17. 
18. RUN dotnet publish "./Func_MyFunction.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
19. 
20. FROM base AS final
21. WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
22. COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
23. ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

This is the error:
#14 [build 8/8] RUN playwright install
#14 0.415 /bin/sh: 1: playwright: not found
#14 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c playwright install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
------
 > [build 8/8] RUN playwright install:
0.415 /bin/sh: 1: playwright: not found
------
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |     RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Playwright
  15 |     RUN dotnet build "./Func_MyFunction.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
  16 | >>> RUN playwright install
  17 |     
  18 |     FROM build AS publish
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c playwright install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127


Can you please share your function code?

I am able to install playwright using the below docker file.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp63/FunctionApp63.csproj", "FunctionApp63/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./FunctionApp63/FunctionApp63.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp63"
RUN dotnet build "./FunctionApp63.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# Install Playwright
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g playwright
RUN playwright install

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./FunctionApp63.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

Upon building the docker image, I am getting below output and playwright got installed successfully to the src folder.


Thank you! I moved 'WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp63"' to above 'COPY ..'.

There were a couple of errors I had. One was this:
'Driver not found: /home/site/wwwroot/bin/.playwright/node/linux-x64/node'

The solution can be found here.
In the .csproj file add:
<PlaywrightPlatform>all</PlaywrightPlatform>

The other error was:
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: 'Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-xxxx/....'

The root cause was that I was installing playwright in the wrong order of the Dockerfile. It should have been in the 'base' and not 'build'. Also, needed to install playwright dependencies. Here's a working Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0 AS base
# Install Playwright
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npx playwright install

# Install Playwright depedencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
     libglib2.0-0\
     libnss3\                 
     libnspr4\                
     libdbus-1-3\             
     libatk1.0-0\             
     libatk-bridge2.0-0\      
     libcups2\                
     libdrm2\                 
     libatspi2.0-0\           
     libxcomposite1\          
     libxdamage1\             
     libxext6\                
     libxfixes3\              
     libxrandr2\              
     libgbm1\                 
     libxkbcommon0\           
     libpango-1.0-0\          
     libcairo2\               
     libasound2  

WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Func_MyFunction/Func_MyFunction.csproj", "Func_MyFunction/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Func_MyFunction/Func_MyFunction.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN ls -la
WORKDIR "/src/Func_MyFunction"
RUN dotnet build "./Func_MyFunction.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Func_MyFunction.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN ls -la
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

